# Need to add a class or a style for the mat-select-option’s div only inside the paginator in Angular 9

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Can anyone help me to find a solution for the following image that I  have attached?

i.e. `mat-select-option`'s `container` `div` inside the `mat-paginator` should need an additional class or style for that `div`.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="sample">
    <mat-option>one</mat-option>
    <mat-option>two</mat-option>
    <mat-option>three</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="sample2">
    <mat-option>one</mat-option>
    <mat-option>two</mat-option>
    <mat-option>three</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</div>

<table >

<!--Here is the following mat-paginator's [pageSize]="[10, 15, 20]" that generates the mat-select with the options 10, 15, 20 -->

<mat-paginator [length]="totalRecords" [pageSize]="[10, 15, 20]" [pageSizeOptions]="1.pageSizeOptions"
    showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>

</table>

</main-componont>
```

[image: enter image description here][1]

Comment: would you mind adding a stackbliz link, so that it would be easier for others to get into your problem quickly ?

Answer (score 2):

Create component for paginator, add viewProviders with overlayPanelClass

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-paginator",
    templateUrl: "./paginator.component.html",
    viewProviders: [
        {
            provide: MAT_SELECT_CONFIG,
            useValue: {
                overlayPanelClass: "paginator-panel-class"
            } as MatSelectConfig
        }
    ]
})
```

with this in css file, you can access mat-option

```
.paginator-panel-class mat-option {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me understand how this will work with `<mat-paginator>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since Material creates the dropdown list dynamically, so you will have to bind a custom click events to your paginator dropdown and add the class to the mat-option every time user opens the paginator dropdown (not anyother dropdown) something like this:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const dropdown = document.querySelector(
      '.mat-paginator-container mat-select'
    );
    console.log('dropdown', dropdown);
    dropdown.addEventListener('click', (evnt) => {
      const list = document.querySelectorAll(
        '.mat-select-panel-wrap .mat-option'
      );
      console.log('list', list);
      list.forEach((element) => {
        element.classList.add('paginator-option');
      });
    });
  }
```

Also, use following component css inside the css file:

```
::ng-deep .mat-option.paginator-option {
  color: aqua;
}
```

Demo: [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-mattable-crud-ggdb49?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.you need to use ng-deep.

```
:host ::ng-deep.mat-paginator .mat-paginator-container{
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sanjay,

Thanks for the response. Kindly review the attached image for more clarification : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNxAO.png 

Have to change style for select option's container only not for mat-paginator container

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a simple CSS class which you'll have to add to every element or change the root class for the element and have it change everywhere... I am not sure what exactly are you targeting but here is what I mean.

This will change all mat options once added to your main style.css file

```
.mat-option{
  color: red !important;
}
```

This will change only elements that have this class, the class could be added to the component's CSS file or to the main style.css file as well...

```
.sample-class {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ahmed adel,

Thanks for your response.

I need to change mat-option, only inside the mat-paginator component. 

I have tried various methods including pseudo elemnts like :host and :ng-deep. but it never works

Answer (score -1):

The answer is no you can't do that in angular 9,
As the component adds the div
`<div class="cdk-overlay-container">` right inside the `body` section, and every select drop down renders in this global space, so you can't only select a single drop down,
Please upgate to newer angular versions. That's my suggestion

Comment: I managed to do it with a workaround

Comment: would be helpful if you post the workaround